# JVM пропускает System.in.read и выполняет программу дальше JAVA

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.*;


class DZkalkulator {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    double var1;
    double var2;
    double result;
    char operator;

    System.out.println ("Введите первое число");
    var1 = (double)System.in.read();

    System.out.println ("Введите второе число");// 
    var2 = (double)System.in.read();Вот этот момент JVM пропускает


    System.out.println ("Выберите операцию");
    System.out.println ("1. Сложение \n" + "2. Вычитание \n" + "3.  Умножение \n" + "4. Деление" );
```

Собственно, первый System.in выполняется, после ввода числа в консоль, появляется всё остальное, не давая ввести второе число , выглядит всё вот так:
Введите первое число
2. 
Введите второе число // вот отсюда программа идёт дальше
Выберите операцию
1. Сложение 
2. Вычитание 
3. Умножение 
4. Деление

Comment: Компилятор не ошибается, `System.in.read` считывает один символ

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `Scanner`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double var1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    double var2 = scanner.nextDouble();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, я и сам хотел либо так, либо через bufferedreader сделать, но это домашка, и предполагается что Scanner и bufferedreader я еще не знаю

Answer (score 0):

1) Если еще раз напишете:

> Компилятор пропускает `System.in.read()`

то получите **жырный минус** - прогу выполняет не компилятор, а JVM

2) `System.in.read()` читает 1 байт, включая тот который находится в буфере клавиатуры, соответственно ввод первого числа обработается 1-м `System.in.read()` а нажатие `enter` обработается уже вторым `System.in.read()` - отсюда и пропуск.

3) Для чтения с клавиатуры существует специальный класс `Scanner`, на который вам указали в комментариях или как вариант можете поизвращаться с `InputStreamReader.readLine()`, который умеет читать символы, а не байты.

Comment: 1)не ругайтесь, я только начал) но теперь буду знать
2) понятно, спасибо за разъяснения
3) А такой вопрос, есть ли смысл считывать сканнером тип переменной char? Когда я делал программу и там не было double, а только char, все работало замечательно